# Unable to install Unity tweak tool in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dependencies, unity-tweak-tool

I had Installed "Unity Tweak Tool". But now it disappeared.

When I tried to install again it shows the following output
`sudo apt-get install unity-tweak-tool`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 unity-tweak-tool : Depends: unity-webapps-common but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Screenshot -

[image]

Comment: What happens if you run `sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-common` ?

Comment: @M.Becerra plz see this screenshot [Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/3ahFlmb.png)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get -f install` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

Comment: same problem [screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/VISVEIy.png)

Comment: Whats the output of `sudo less /etc/apt/sources.list` and  `locate /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Comment: for [sudo less /etc/apt/sources.list](http://pastebin.com/5BVehcc3)

for [locate /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list](http://pastebin.com/uFgLZBBB)

Comment: Go to *System Settings>Software and updates>Ubuntu Software*, do you have all the **downloadable from internet** items checked?

Comment: `Source code ` is not checked.